# zip some directories recursively and others not in a single command?

Tags: macos, command-line, zip

I'd like to do a single-command backup of a number of folders and files on my OSX machine.  The problem is the root directory.

Basically, I want to zip up
- all the files in the root of my home dir (~) but *not* to recurse
- recursively get the contents of ~/Documents, ~/Music, ~/Pictures

Basically: how do I tell zip to use -r for some directories and not others, or is there another way?  I do not want to use tar (I want an encrypted archive) and would prefer to not have to install another tool e.g. 7zip.

Answer (score 1):

`-@` tells zip to read the list of files to archive from stdin. You can use the `find` command to list the files you want and pipe them to zip.

e.g., in your home directory execute:

```
( find . -type f -maxdepth 1 ; find Documents ) | zip backup.zip -@
```

The first find lists the top level files in the current directory, the second lists everything in *Documents* recursively.